# xmlHTTPrequest won't open ("GET" , url, true); I'm miffed! PHP

Tags: javascript, php, url, get

I've been trying to get a url to open but I'm miffed as to why this hasn't worked. The code is listed and explained below. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

The object:

```
function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
   var req =  false;
   try {
      /* for Firefox */
      req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
   } catch (err) {
      try {
         /* for some versions of IE */
         req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (err) {
         try {
            /* for some other versions of IE */
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (err) {
            req = false;
         }
     }
   }

   return req;
}
```

The object is called like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myDelete = new getXMLHTTPRequest();
</script>
```

Now here's what I want to do:

```
function removeArticle(id) {

    if (myDelete) {

        try {
            var deletUrl = "delete.php";
            var query = deletUrl + "?theid=" + id;
            myDelete.open("GET", query, true);
            myDelete.onreadystatechange = removeArticleResponse;
            myDelete.send(null);
        } catch (e) {
            alert ("Unable to connect to the server:\n" + e.toString());
        }
    } else {
        alert ("Bad! Very BAD!");
    }
}
```

When I do this:

```
        if (myDelete.open("GET", query, true)) {
        myDelete.onreadystatechange = removeArticleResponse;
        myDelete.send(null);
        } else {
            alert ("No road!");
        }
```

The alert("No road!"); shows me that the code doesn't execute passed this point:

```
if (myDelete.open("GET", query, true)) {
```

This means that the if (myDelete) { works. The code passes this stage and for some reason stops here: myDelete.open("GET", query, true); It won't open the url. I'm not sure what the problem is.

**Edit:** Here's the function used to access the server response:

```
function removeArticleResponse () {
    if (myDelete.status == 4) {
        if (myDelete.status == 200) {
                        try {
                            response = myDelete.responseText;
                            document.getElementById('displaynewsletterarticleresult').innerHTML = response;
                        } catch(e) {
                            alert("An error occured while reading the response:" + e.toString());
                        }
        } else {
        alert ("An error occured when attempting to retrieve the data:\n" + myDelete.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using XMLHttpRequest objects directly instead of one of the libraries that abstract the plumbing from you (such as jQuery)?  I don't want to make assumptions, but if you're not aware of them, they save you ALOT of hassle w/ajax (and JS code in general)

Comment: Even loading jQuery just to get a nice Ajax call is a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  your response function, do you mean to check .status == 4 instead of .readyState?

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I now get a response. That was a bone headed mistake.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536648(VS.85).aspx), XMLHttpRequest.open() has no return value, so your check will always fail.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But this means I'm back to square one, not knowing what the problem is in the first place. I get no response from the script I'm sending the parameters to. No error message, nothing. I know the id was passed but after that I'm not sure what's happened. Any ideas? Thanks, a lot!

Comment: I've edited the question to show the function used to access the response from the server.

Comment: Maybe using a debugger like firebug to try to work out what is going on would help? Or just put alert statements everywhere so you can follow the logic

Answer (score 0):

All xmlHTTPRequests are bound to the same origin policy. Maybe that's your issue.

You can read more about it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy